# Make calculations with xsl:number

Tags: xslt

If I use xsl:number, I will get a number as a text of the output document. But how can I add another number to it?
I'm using it to keep track of elements, so to get their index so to speak.
If I say
`<xsl:number/> + $somenumber`
I would get something like 5+6 but not 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the technique suggested by @DanielHaley is best. Sometimes you can use `position()` instead of `xsl:number`. Sometimes it's simplest to use an expression like `count(preceding-sibling::x)` in place of `xsl:number`.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using the technique suggested by DanielHaley, but so far xsl:number only.

Comment: Okay, so I also added the count=* attribute to make it count the elements considering all nodes. I also gave different variable names not to return the same value, just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try storing `xsl:number` in an `xsl:variable` and performing the calculation in an `xsl:value-of` (or an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) if it's going to be an attribute value)...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:variable name="nbr">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <foo attr="{$nbr + 10}"><xsl:value-of select="$nbr + 10"/></foo>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <foo attr="11">11</foo>
   <foo attr="12">12</foo>
   <foo attr="13">13</foo>
   <foo attr="14">14</foo>
   <foo attr="15">15</foo>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position() + $somenumber" />
```

Otherwise you'll have to put the `<xsl:number/>` inside another variable, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$anothervariable + $somenumber" />
```

Comment: position would be good, but as far as I know it is valid for the current node. These elements I need to keep track of may occur in a variety of depths in the tree but I only care about their occurrence as a sequence (one follows the other), not where they are. That's why xsl: number looks good especially with the level=any attribute, I'm not sure if I can do that with position. If I assign this number to a variable, can I use the same variable storing different index numbers? I thought variables are constant in xsl.

Comment: @stevie : "*position would be good, but as far as I know it is valid for the current node.*" Not exactly: it returns the position of the current node in the current node list. How it affects you is difficult to say without seeing your code. ---  "*If I assign this number to a variable, can I use the same variable storing different index numbers?*" I am afraid I don't understand you question. What do you mean by "*different index numbers*"? If the above doesn't work for you, edit your question and show us an example of your XML, XSLT and the expected result.

Comment: :Okay, so now I have the number as the result of the calculation but it is indeed giving me the same result. <xsl:template match="in:RECORDS">
<db:FileCollection>
<db:File>
<xsl variable name="nID">
<xsl:number level="any">
</xsl variable>
<db:FileID><xsl:value-of select='format-number($nID+$someconstant,"#")'> But I have to repeat the part from xsl:variable name (only the element name to which the new ID will be assgned is different) and insert it in other parts of the XSL in different substuctures. Elsewhere, however, I get the same number because I guess it's the same nID.

Comment: @stevie I am afraid I can't follow that. Please do as I advised before and edit your question to include (a minimal example of) your XML input and the expected output.

Comment: Sample input:  <br/> <RECORDS>  <br/><LDN>1</LDN>  <br/><DZD>05/07/2014</DZD>  <br/><BIP>y800</BIP>  <br/> <STB>  <br/><PTD>  <br/><LFM>8</LFM>  <br/><DXR>03/01/2014</DXR>  <br/><BMP>y87600</BPM></PTD>          </STB>  <br/> Expected output:  </br> <br/> <RECORDS>  <br/><ID>548</ID>  </br>  <LDN>1</LDN>  <br/><DZD>05/07/2014</DZD>  <br/><BIP>y800</BIP>  <br/> <STB>  <br/><PTD><ID>549</ID>  <br/><LFM>8</LFM>  <br/><DXR>03/01/2014</DXR>  <br/><BMP>y87600</BPM>  <br/></PTD>          </STB>  I'm afraid I wasn't able to insert linebreaks...

Comment: **Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and post your code there.**